# How to return the array without the brackets javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

So I have this code where I have an array of sentences which are being prompted through a switch where the user is to ask how many sentences they want to display 1 - 5. it will then loop through and randomly display the number of sentences requested from the array.

```js
var sentences = ["sentence one", "sentence two", "sentence three",
  "sentence 4", "sentence 5"];

function shuffle(a) {
  for (i = a.length - 1; i; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    [a[i - 1], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i - 1]];
  }
}

var random = prompt("how many sentences do you want?");
switch (random) {
  case "1":
    shuffle(sentences)
    console.log(sentences(0, 1));
    break;

  case "2":
    shuffle(sentences)
    console.log(sentences.slice(0, 2))
    break;

  case "3":
    shuffle(sentences)
    console.log(sentences.slice(0, 3))
    break;

  case "4":
    shuffle(sentences)
    console.log(sentences.slice(0, 4))
    break;

  case "5":
    shuffle(sentences)
    console.log(sentences.slice(0, 5))
    break;

  default:
    console.log("incorrect number");
}
```

The code works fine, but when it returns, it displays the array of course:
say if the person wanted 3 sentences:

```
(3) ["sentence two", "sentence four", "sentence five"]
```

I want to return the sentences itself and not the array so:

```
sentence two, sentence four, sentence five
```

I tried converting to a string with `.length` but this then returns the number of characters in the string eg prompt entered was 5 so it returns:

```
sente
```

Anyone have any ideas, much appreciated :)

Comment: It's important to note first of all that your code isn't actually _returning_ anything; it's just _logging_ a representation of your array to the console

Comment: If you want to log a prettier representation of your array, one good option is [`array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: `.slice()` always returns an Array. If you're outputting to HTML you can just assign the Array to the `Element.innerHTML` or `Element.value` and it gives you a String without `[]` anyways.

Comment: Why are you using `switch/case`? Just `sentences.slice(0, random)`

Comment: "return array without the brackets". If it doesn't have the brackets, it's not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [join ()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). The join() method joins all elements of an array (or an array-like object) into a string and returns this string.

In your code:

```
 console.log((sentences.slice(0, 3)).join(', '));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by "joining" your array with the [join method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). For example, given an array of `["foo", "bar"]`, calling `["foo", "bar"].join(", ")` will output a string containing `foo, bar`.

Here's an example:

```
> var foo = ['bar', 'bat'];
[ 'bar', 'bat' ]
> foo.join(', ');
'bar, bat'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .slice to strip the brackets before you display it.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp

Or alternatively you can use split:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

OR you can use replace:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you can use the spread `...` operator in ES6.

```
var sentences = ["sentence one", "sentence two", "sentence three", 
"sentence 4", "sentence 5"];

  function shuffle(a) {
        for (i = a.length - 1; i; i--) {
            let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
            [a[i - 1], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i - 1]];
        }
    }

 var random = prompt("how many sentences do you want?");
  switch (random) {
    case "1":
    shuffle(sentences)
   console.log(...sentences(0, 1));
      break;

      case "2":
       shuffle(sentences)
      console.log(...sentences.slice(0, 2))
      break;

      case "3":
       shuffle(sentences)
      console.log(...sentences.slice(0, 3))
      break;

      case "4":
       shuffle(sentences)
      console.log(...sentences.slice(0, 4))
      break;

      case "5":
       shuffle(sentences)
      console.log(...sentences.slice(0, 5))
      break;

      default:
      console.log("incorrect number");
}
```

As a side note, the switch statement is repetitive and unnecessary:

```
 var random = +prompt("how many sentences do you want?");
 if (0 <= random <= 5) {
   shuffle(sentences);
   console.log(...sentences.slice(0, random));
 } else {
   console.log("invalid number");
 }
```

Here, `+` casts the number string to a number. You can also explicitly cast using `Number(prompt(..))`.

---

EDIT: I see that now you want to insert comma between elements.

You can use `Array.prototype.join`.

```
 var random = +prompt("how many sentences do you want?");
 if (0 <= random <= 5) {
   shuffle(sentences);
   console.log(sentences.slice(0, random).join(', ');
 } else {
   console.log("invalid number");
 }
```

Comment: Glad I helped!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to concatenate all the values from the array with a string (like `', '`)

```js
var sentences = ["sentence one", "sentence two", "sentence three",
  "sentence 4", "sentence 5"];

function shuffle(a) {
  for (i = a.length - 1; i; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    [a[i - 1], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i - 1]];
  }
}

var random = prompt("how many sentences do you want?");

shuffle(sentences);

switch (random) {
  case "1":
    sentences = sentences.slice(0, 1);
    break;

  case "2":
    sentences = sentences.slice(0, 2);
    break;

  case "3":
    sentences = sentences.slice(0, 3);
    break;

  case "4":
    sentences = sentences.slice(0, 4)
    break;

  case "5":
    sentences = sentences.slice(0, 5);
    break;

  default:
    console.log("incorrect number");
}

console.log(sentences.join(', '));
```